# org.apache.http.legacy doesn't work on API 28

Tags: android, apache, http

To begin with, I was using org.apache.http functions for a while now and error came when I tried to launch my app on API 28. It's working on API 26 and API 23, but suddenly something is wrong with API 28. Did Google made some changes?

Comment: "Something is wrong" is not a really good description of the error you are facing

Comment: very important question. Thanks

Answer (score 35):

To run org.apache.http.legacy perfectely in Android 9.0 Pie create an xml file `res/xml/network_security_config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <network-security-config>
      <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
       <trust-anchors>
        <certificates src="system" />
       </trust-anchors>
      </base-config>
    </network-security-config>
```

And add 2 tags tag in your AndroidManifest.xml

> android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
>   android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest......>
  <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">
   <activity..../> 
   ......
   ......
 <uses-library
        android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
        android:required="false"/>
</application>
```

Also add `useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'` in your app build gradle

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "your application id"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

Comment: The only thing that solved the issue for me. Spent almost a day making out with this problem. Thank you!

Comment: Amazing, it works like a champ. You saved my day bro!

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day!

Comment: Thank you very much. Great Help, Bro.

Answer (score 6):

**Step 1:**
create an xml file in `res/xml/network_security_config.xml` and copy the below code in it,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">your.website.domain</domain> <!-- the domain you are using for api network call -->
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

**Step 2:**
now in your `Manifest.xml` add `android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"` under the `<application>` tag. Done!

Comment: This worked! I was using 
   `implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.10.0"`
And on Android 9 requests always returned null.

Answer (score 6):

You just need to do two things:

1-Put in your AndroidManifest.xml the next line under `<application>`

`<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>`

2-Change the Url being invoke to HTTPS instead of HTTP

After I did that the error goes away and my app worked again.

Comment: These 2 steps worked for me even in the mid of 2020.. ;-) Thanks man you saved my day

Answer (score 1):

[Apache HTTP client deprecation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-28#apache-p)

> With Android 6.0, we removed support for the Apache HTTP client.
>   Beginning with Android 9, that library is removed from the
>   bootclasspath and is not available to apps by default.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I resolved it by using HTTPS, instead of HTTP. Apparently, a secure connection is now required.