# why volley library not working on android 9(API 28) where as its working fine on android 8(API 27)?

Tags: android, android-volley

I am developing an app with volley library. Everything is working fine below android 9.0. But not in 9.0

I am using

```
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
targetSdkVersion 28
compileSdkVersion 28
minSdkVersion 24
```

gradle:3.2.1

Comment: https://github.com/google/volley/issues/235

Comment: Please paste any error log or any issue while you compile on `28`. becoz i also use volley in  28 and it's working fine

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53739479/1117696

Comment: @Ali #bro
I am sorry to paste that. because my android 9.0 phone not worked as developer. that's why, if you have any suggestion, please

thanks again

Comment: use version 1.1.1 and check

Comment: @UTTAMKUMAR *because my android 9.0 phone not worked as developer.* You mean your device didn't connect with android studio for **run** the app??

Comment: @Ali
yes i meant that. & sorry to say my phone is manually updated as 8 to 9.

Comment: Then please update your question becoz your issue is not related to volley. @UTTAMKUMAR

Comment: @Ali
without android 9.0 it is working fine. I have used volley to retrieve an url, without android 9 the url retrieves but on 9.0 it doesn't.. but in both others function working fine

Comment: wait wait can you please clarify your issue. `9.0` Device not connect with android studio??? or data didn't get on `9.0`??@UTTAMKUMAR

Comment: @Ali My device could not connected with android studio. But its not my issue currently. My Issue is here, On Android 9.0, could not get url through volley library where as below Android 9.0 could

Comment: okay i paste my answer you check and tell me it's work for you or not. @UTTAMKUMAR

Comment: @Ali .. thanks, it works fine now. but why it did not work for
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
targetSdkVersion 28
compileSdkVersion 28
minSdkVersion 24

Comment: if my answer is helpful for you then mark as a right answer. *but why it did not work for implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0' targetSdkVersion 28 compileSdkVersion 28 minSdkVersion 24* **please follow this doc link** : https://github.com/google/volley/wiki/Release-Notes @UTTAMKUMAR

Comment: did you try to use https ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update** :

Please add below line in manifests:

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

First, You check your `Offline` mode is check or Unchecked. if it's check then please go on setting and Unchecked.

Now change the below version :

```
compileSdkVersion 27
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 27

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'

implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
```

Now **`Clean`** and **`Re-Build`** your Project.

Comment: not working for me, is there any solutions available on this?

Comment: @Rajesh I update my answer please add this and work like charm..... :)

Answer (score 13):

From android 9 clear text traffic is prohibited. You will manually need to allow it adding below code to manifest.

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

Also, **create xml/network_security_config.xml** and add below code to allow clear text traffic:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Answer (score 5):

Just add one line manifest file.

```
 android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Answer (score -1):

I have same problem and resolved it when I use https not http.