# Volley does not seem to work with Android SDK 29

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I want to access `JSONobject` from my rest API using Volley in SDK version 29, but I am getting timeout error.

I had tried the same code before in other versions then it is working.

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

    String data = "";
    String url = "http://xyz/abc";
    TextView tv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
        Button button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.lgn) ;
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // making json object request
                getObject();
            }
        });
        tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtResponse);

    }

    public void getObject(){
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        StringRequest strRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
        {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams()
            {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("abc", "xyz");
                params.put("abc", "xyz");
                params.put("abc", "xyz");
                return params;
            }
        };

        queue.add(strRequest);
        //VolleySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(req);
    }
}
```

I want to get response of my `JSONobject` using volley in SDK version 29.

Comment: what about older versions? Does your code work on them?

Comment: yes it is working for them

Comment: it is your code problem, still trying to use http, not https. have you set the rules in your config?

Answer (score 1):

This is a POST but you pass no body. Try overriding the `getBody()` method as you did for `getParams()`.

Something like this should work

```
@Override
    public byte[] getBody() {
        String parsedBody = new String();
        try {
            parsedBody = parseBody(body); /* write a function to parse the body into a String */
            return parsedBody == null ? null : parsedBody.getBytes("utf-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
            VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s", parsedBody, "utf-8");
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: as stated in https://github.com/google/volley/issues/235 you might want to create a network config file, follow [Asad' asnwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53739479/8949981)

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is blocked by default since Pie (SDK level 28).
Please read this for more info.
https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/08/introducing-android-9-pie.html

Please refer to this for solution. [How to allow all Network connection types HTTP and HTTPS in Android (9) Pie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51902629/how-to-allow-all-network-connection-types-http-and-https-in-android-9-pie)

Answer (score -1):

Try to add this **compileOptions** in **build.gradle** inside android tag

```
android {
  ...
  // Configure only for each module that uses Java 8
  // language features (either in its source code or
  // through dependencies).
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
}
```