# 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException"' after migrating to target API Level 28

Tags: android, api, android-studio, android-appcompat

First of all, sorry for bad English.

Guys, I have an old project with minsdk 14 and compil/target 22. I did change to 28 for upload in google play. Changed all to AppCompatActivity at java files and did import. But have a problem with an apk.

No mistakes in code, no mistakes at 'run'app. But the app doesn't open, every time mistake.

new gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
    compileOptions.encoding = 'windows-1251' //кодировка
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.my.app"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

new java example

```
package com.my.app;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;

public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
```

old gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'
    compileOptions.encoding = 'windows-1251' //кодировка
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.my.app"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.9.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/bolts-android-1.2.0.jar')
}
```

old java example

```
package com.my.app;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class Activity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
```

and saw that in run

```
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-1-thread-3
        Process: com.my,app, PID: 30993
        java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/client/ClientProtocolException;
            at com.parse.ParseRequest$2.then(ParseRequest.java:195)
            at com.parse.ParseRequest$2.then(ParseRequest.java:190)
            at bolts.Task$14.run(Task.java:796)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
         Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.my.app-A1k1kce0AmLrPJ8ojgBekA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.my.app-A1k1kce0AmLrPJ8ojgBekA==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
            at com.parse.ParseRequest$2.then(ParseRequest.java:195) 
            at com.parse.ParseRequest$2.then(ParseRequest.java:190) 
            at bolts.Task$14.run(Task.java:796) 
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.my.app-A1k1kce0AmLrPJ8ojgBekA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.my.app-A1k1kce0AmLrPJ8ojgBekA==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at com.parse.ParseRequest$2.then(ParseRequest.java:195) 
        at com.parse.ParseRequest$2.then(ParseRequest.java:190) 
        at bolts.Task$14.run(Task.java:796) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: And what does `logcat` say?

Comment: @Michael only that `2020-03-03 18:53:00.748 19764-31820/com.my.app I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false`

Comment: @Michael I updated my ask, please look at code

Comment: Well, apparently that bolts library is trying to use a class that no longer exists in Android (see https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes#behavior-apache-http-client). Have you tried upgrading to a newer version of bolts? Do you even need the library?

Comment: @Michael I don't think is a library problem, because yesterday I tried api 26, without any manipulations with java (only gladle sync) an app worked

Comment: Things change depending on which targetSdkVersion you're using. Such as https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-28#apache-p

Comment: @Michael I did that [https://stackoverflow.com/a/55121645/12913883] but now have white screen

Comment: @Michael do you have any ideas?

Comment: Either the issue is lack of Legacy Apache Client Library on higher API levels, or you have apache client version mismatch

Answer (score 0):

The Apache HTTP client was removed by default in Android 6.0.  To keep using it, add this to the `android { ... }` block in your build.gradle:

```
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
```

See [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes#behavior-apache-http-client) for more information on the removal.

Comment: I added in gradle, but no result =(

Comment: I did that [https://stackoverflow.com/a/55121645/12913883] but now have white screen

Comment: only that `2020-03-03 20:31:40.606 22021-22021/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
2020-03-03 20:31:40.607 22021-22021/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 1`

Comment: do you have any ideas?